# Jersey2 with Spring3: Abstract class JSON serialization and missing properties

Tags: java, json, spring, jackson, jersey-2.0

I'm using Jersey-spring3 v2.17

All is working fine. Objects serialized from REST services are correctly exposed with JSON format.

Only objects from abstract classes are not correctly serialized. Only the type of the concrete class is present and correctly defined in the JSON object.

Some information regarding my configuration:
Jersey / Jackson configuration in the Application configuration class:

```
register(JacksonFeature.class);
```

The abstract class:

```
    @JsonTypeInfo(use = JsonTypeInfo.Id.NAME, include = JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY, property = "type")  
    @JsonSubTypes({  
            @Type(value = Dog.class, name = "dog"), 
            @Type(value = Cat.class, name = "cat"), 
            @Type(value = Horse.class, name = "horse") })
    public abstract class Animal {
private String name;
private String description
    ...
```

Output is currently on this format (no object property are present)

```
[{"type":"dog"},{"type":"cat"},{"type":"horse"}]
```

Any idea to fix my issue regarding missing properties in my JSON output ?

Comment: Do you have public getters declared in our abstract class?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend adding `@JsonProperty` on each property that you want serialized in the abstract class.  Also, I recommend using `@JsonPropertyOrder` on the class to control the order of the serialized fields.

A caveat with property order is that the the type property will always be listed first for JsonTypeInfo.As.PROPERTY regardless of what you put into `@JsonPropertyOrder`.  If your sub-classes actually provide the type via a getter, then you can use `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` in which case you can then control even the order of that property if I remember correctly.  Support for `JsonTypeInfo.As.EXISTING_PROPERTY` functionality was added to jackson-databind-2.5.0.